# Font Awesome with Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-awesome

I am trying to get Font Awesome working with my rails app following:
http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

I do not wish to use the CDN as I also want to use other fonts that have no CDN so I want to understand how to get non CDN fonts working:
https://github.com/540co/govicons

I have downloaded and extracted Font Awesome into:

```
/app/assets/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0
```

I don't know if I am using CSS or SASS? In my stylesheets folder I have files with both `css` and `sass` extensions. I have an `application.css` file and an empty `application.scss` file. All my other files have the `scss` extension.

If I follow the `scss` instructions then step 2 is:

> Open your project's font-awesome/less/variables.less or
>   font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss and edit the @fa-font-path or
>   $fa-font-path variable to point to your font directory.

This file is located in:

```
/app/assets/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/scss/_variables.scss
```

This variable currently reads:

> $fa-font-path:        "../fonts" !default;

What should this be updated to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move these into `vendor/assets` instead of `app/assets` because ([source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization))

> `vendor/assets` is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks

```
mkdir -p vendor/assets
mv font-awesome-4.7.0/ vendor/assets/
ls vendor/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/
# css       fonts       less        scss
```

and then if you're using `application.css`, you can just:

1. Edit `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`
2. Add: `*= require css/font-awesome` in the list of requires
3. Restart the server and load the page

and everything should be working fine

If you want to use this in SCSS:

1. Add `app/assets/stylesheets/font_awesome.scss` with the contents:

   ```
   $fa-font-path: "fonts";
   @import "scss/font-awesome";
   ```
2. Add `@import "font_awesome";` to `application.scss`

The purpose of doing it this way is now you don't have any custom changes to the files in `vendor/assets`. Those are exactly what you downloaded from the site and can be updated at any time without worrying about whether you're going to remember that `$fa-font-path` was changed to a custom path because that was done in your files, not theirs.

Note: Usually you'd want to use one of the helpers (like `asset-path`) for the paths in assets, but it doesn't seem to like being used with a folder as a placeholder with files given later. So, without wanting to hunt through font-awesome and replace `$fa-font-path` with `asset-path`, we can do this, which will look from the current folder (in the address bar, which will be something like `#{host}/assets/application-#{cache-buster}.css` so the current folder is `/assets` and it will look for `/assets/fonts` which is what we want (read: what works for me going through this example).

Govicons, looks like you'd follow the exact same steps above and should work out fine.